# Resize file data image .PNG in Python

Tags: python

```
import Image
import os  
def resize_file(fname):
    width, height = get_image_size(fname) /// get_image_size return width and height ///
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(fname)
    new_image_file = "%s%s%s" %(name, 'new' , ext)
    im1 = Image.open(fname)
    im5 = im1.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    ext2 = ".jpg"
    im5.save(name + 'new' + ext2)
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open(name + 'new' + ext2)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    resize_file('/home/kirito/Desktop/HD_69830_Planet.jpg')
    resize_file('/home/kirito/Desktop/cod2.png')
```

* My problem : line  when I change ext2 = ".png" data file not change. but when ext2 = ".jpg" data size down (case true). I want change image.png data file size down and result still image.png !

Comment: You're redimensioning to the height - width of the original image? No wonder the size does'nt change....

Comment: I want change file size. not change height - width.

Comment: for example : image cod2.png has size file 5 MB, I want change size file image cod2.png < 5MB ( about 500KB). without change height - width and quality !

Comment: Ok, then you want to change the compression rate. Youcan't do it with a png because it's a loseless format. To get a smaller file with a constant image size (width-height) your only option is change the color depth or subsample it. before creating your png Jpg is a losy? format and you can squeeze it at will when building te file.

Comment: what about loseless format. I don't understand.

Comment: A loseless format as png allows to recover  the exact pixel values of the original image from the compressed file. A lossy format does some assumptions about what the human eye can and can't see and removes the "non relevant" information so it can reduce the size of the file. This way you have an image "undistinguishable" from the original - until you zoom it and find the artifacts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close !

A lossless format, such as PNG, allows one to recover the exact pixel values of the original image from the compressed file. A lossy format makes some assumptions about what the human eye can and can't see, and removes the "non relevant" information to reduce the size of the file. This way, you have an image visually indistinguishable from the original - until you zoom it and find the artifacts.